# Using DeviceEventEmitter.addListener inside a react-native module

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to receive a custom event through DeviceEventEmitter, inside my custom react-native module. I'm invoking:

```
DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('scanNotify',(event)=>{
    console.log("scanNotify in lib", event); 
});
```

Notice that **that code is at the module level, outside of the App lifecycle methods**.

And in the app I fire an event:

```
DeviceEventEmitter.emit('scanNotify', { message: 'from App (DeviceEventEmitter)' });;
```

But the listener in the module isn't invoked. If I put the listener into the App itself, it works. Is it normal? Am I even allowed to listen to stuff inside a module?

Comment: did you manage to fix this?